# Best way to throttle an external application's CPU Usage

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, cpu, throttling

Ok - here is the scenario:
I host a server application on Amazon AWS hosted windows instances. (I do not have access to the source code - so I cannot resolve the issues from within the applications source code)
These specific instances are able to build up CPU credits during times of idle cpu (less than 10-20% usage) and then spend those CPU credits during times of increased compute requirement.

My server application however, typically runs at around 15-20% cpu usage when no clients are connected- this is time when I would rather lower the cpu usage to around 5% through throttling of the cpu - maintaining enough cpu throughput to accept a TCP Socket from incoming clients.

When a connected client is detected, I would like to remove the throttle and allow full access to the reserve of AWS CPU Credits.

I have got code in place that can Suspend and Resume processes via C# using Windows API calls.
I am however a bit fuzzy on how to accurately attain a target cpu usage for that process.

What I am doing so far, which is having moderate success:
Looping inside another application
 check the cpu usage of the server application - using performance counters (dont like these - they require a 100-1000 ms wait in order to return a % value)
I determine if the current value is above or below the target value - if above, I increase an int value called 'sleep' by 10ms
If below - 'sleep' is decreased by 10ms.

Then the application will call

```
Process.Suspend();
Threads.sleep(sleep);
Process.Resume();
```

Like I said - this is having moderate success.
But there are several reasons I don't like it:
 1. It requires a semi-rapid loop in an external application: This might end up just shifting cpu usage to that application.
 2. Im sure there are better mathematical solutions to work out the ideal sleep time.

I came across this application : http://mion.faireal.net/BES/
It seems to do everything I want, except I need to be able to control it, and I am not a c++ developer.
It also seems to be able to achieve accurate cpu throttling without consuming large cpu utself.
Can someone suggest CPU throttle techniques.
Remember - I **cannot** modify the source code of the application being throttled - at most, I could inject code into it: but it occurs to me that if I inject suspend code into it, then the resume code could not fire etc.
An external agent program might be the best way to go.

Comment: Golly what's it doing for 15-20% CPU on idle?  I don't know much about AWS but is it possible to set a process's priority to `below-normal` as per Windows Task Manager?  That requires no change to the code and you could make an app to set it.  You could also increase it during high demand?

Comment: *"enough cpu throughput to accept a TCP Socket from incoming clients"* ... in a well-written application, that would be approximately 0% CPU.  Worse, if you can starve it for cycles and it still works fine, that suggests it's not getting backlogged and therefore not doing any genuinely useful work, and you do have a serious problem, there, with badly-written code.  Unfortunately, scheduling priority shouldn't make a difference, since it's not competing with other processes for CPU time.  How would you know when it actually needs the cycles it's consuming, anyway?

Comment: Valid points- setting the priority however won't work in this case- as the server application is carrying out passive tasks within itself - (it's a game server- which fires heart beat scripts and performs micro management for every interconnected area and the creatures within those areas. So in an OS where no other apps are draining CPU, even a low priority process will still run as it normaly does- with nothing to compete against. The server application responds to a UDP data gram revealing the amount of connected clients- I could watch this to determine when to apply the throttle.

Comment: How did you go with this? I'm having the same problem. I've resorted to completely suspending the application unless the computer is idle.

Comment: The problem for me in this situation was that while the process is suspended, It is impossible for it to respond to queries that indicate its load. 
So I had to do as mentioned above - Stop the Process and Start the process (suspend and resume) rapidly.
I used an integer value for the amount of milliseconds to suspend the process for, and also used some c# perf mon code to detect the current estimated CPU load generated by the process at its current operating speed. If my target was 20% load, but it was actually at 50%, I would increase the milliseconds to increase suspend time n vice versa

Comment: Battle Encoder Shirase has command line arguments, so you could try to control it that way. But really, the proper solution is to figure out why the application is using 20% CPU while idle, which is clearly a bug.